# How to get path_name in recursive funciton javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested-loops

I created recursive function for listing all files and folder,I am listing fine but I need path name also how to append please help me.

```
const treeData = [
  {
    name: "root",
    children: [
      { name: "src", children: [{ name: "index.html" }] },
      { name: "public", children: [] },
    ],
  },
];

const RecursiveTree = (data) => {
  data.map((item) => {
    console.log(item.name);
    if (item.children) {
      RecursiveTree(item.children);
    }
  });
};

RecursiveTree(treeData);
```

How to get with pathname
Expected result

```
root
root/src
root/src/index.html
```

Comment: `children[]` should be `children : []` (typo, probably). Also your `.map` function isn't returning anything, it should. Or use `forEach` if you're not interested in what `map` returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an optional `path=''` argument, start empty, and then pass itself the current path :

```js
const treeData = [{
  name: 'root',
  children : [{
    name: 'src',
    children: [{
      name: 'index.html'
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'public',
    children: []
  }]
}];

const RecursiveTree = (data, path='') => {
  data.forEach((item) => {
    const currentPath = path + "/" + item.name
    console.log(currentPath )
    if (item.children) {
      RecursiveTree(item.children, currentPath)
    }
  })
}

RecursiveTree(treeData)
```

Answer (score 1):

To append a node name to the previous result, you have to somehow pas the nested structure. One way to do this would be through the function parameters. In the solution below I'll pass the current path as an array.

```js
const treeData = [
  {
    name: "root",
    children: [
      { name: "src", children: [{ name: "index.html" }] },
      { name: "public", children: [] },
    ],
  },
];

function recursiveTree(tree, currentPath = [], paths = []) {
  if (!tree) return;
  
  for (const node of tree) {
    const nodePath = currentPath.concat(node.name);
    paths.push(nodePath.join("/"));
    recursiveTree(node.children, nodePath, paths);
  }
  
  return paths;
}

console.log(recursiveTree(treeData));
```